# How to validate string for "@" symbol and pass to if statement

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know what is wrong with the following code.

```
public void onClickSave (View cs)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userid);
    boolean found = matcher.find();

      if(found){
         //do stuff
```

So the objective is to check the string for an @ symbol. Not sure what I'm missing new to Java. Thanks for any help

Comment: any reason not to say: if (userid.contains("@")) {...} ?

Comment: When you say you want to know what is wrong, are you just asking about the efficiency/good design of the code, or are you getting some sort of error?  Because the inefficiency is obvious, but if it isn't working for some reason you haven't made that clear.  Also, where are you declaring userid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you dont try to use the contains method ?

```
String userID = "@Test";
boolean found = userID.contains("@");
```

But this is also working for me:

```
String userID = "@Test";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*@.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userID);
boolean found = matcher.find();
```

Comment: Many Thanks to all. much appreciated. I wish I could give a check to all.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is overkill here, you can accomplish the same thing with the `contains` method,

```
if(userid.contains("@")){
   //Do something.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(userid.contains("@") {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use `String#contains`, or

1. Transform string into a character array
2. Iterate over each character until the `@` character is found, if at all

Using regex for such a trivial task is unnecessary and overly complex.